# Would IronPython allow me to use Python in a C# Project without adding new requirements for deployment?

Tags: c#, python, asp.net-mvc, ironpython

I have looked at the IronPython website and done various Google searches as well as searching answers on SO and am still not sure about this.

I want to use Python within a C# ASP.NET MVC project such that once the project is deployed I don't need to have Python running on the server that is hosting the application.

I think that is what IronPython does but I am not certain because the description does not seem very specific (or I am just an epic noob).

I could define an object in C# that would basically contain Python scripts, right? Perhaps this all seems to good to be true which is why I am asking, is there a catch here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to have a Python interpreter installed. All you need is the DLR and the IronPython assemblies deployed with your site. Then you could host IronPython inside your application and execute Python scripts and even retrieve the results back in C#.

And [here's an example](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/Using_Python_Classes_from_.NET/CSharp_IP_2.6) of hosting the DLR in a console application.

Comment: so does this mean I could fairly easily create my own little Python IDE in .NET?